# Proving Language accepted by DFA

Tags: automata

I am stuck with a problem, as my proving skills aren't good(trying to improve).
Prob:
Given a State Table of DFA, decribe what language is accepted, and prove by induction it accepts that language, use induction on length of string.

```
              | 0  1 
          ->A | B  A
            B | C  A
           *C | C  C
```

As it accepts language, stings with at least one 00 in them.
Basis: let w be the string, s.t w = 00
           dlt-hat(A,w) = C   as C is accepting state

What would be Inductive Hypothesis, i know there will be cases like 
w = za, where z could be sting with not containing 00, or containg last symbol as 0 and a could be 0 or 1.

@copper.hat, 
 Let w = x00y such that x cannot contain 00 and it ends with 1 and y can be any things {0,1}* 
 Basis: For basis clause let x and y be empty (e) 
 1: del-hat(A,e) = A
 2: del-hat(A,00) = C
 3: del-hat(C, e) = C
 Induction:
 1) Let x=z1 and Inductive hypothesis(IH) be del-hat(A,z) = A.
 del-hat(A,x) = del-hat(A,z1) = del-hat(del-hat(A,z),1) = del-hat(A,1) {from IH}
 And del-hat(A,1)=A.
 2) del-hat(A,00) = A, as basis clause.
 3) let y = za where a can be {0,1}* and Inductive hypothesis be del-hat(C,z) = C
 del-hat(C,za) = del-hat(del-hat(C,z),a) = del-hat(C,a) [from IH] which is C.
 Hence all three cases have been shown.

Comment: Draw the FSM and guess. Hint: To get to $C$, you must have $00$ in the string. Show that any string that does not have $00$ as a substring cannot be accepted. If a string has a $00$ in it, split the string into three parts, the part before the first $00$, the $00$ and the part afterwards. Show the first part always ends in $A$ (any $0$ must be followed by a $1$).

Comment: you mean for these three cases i use mutual induction..

Comment: @copper.hat <br/> Thanx for help, i have edited the post and posed solution, would you please take a look and kindly suggest me if i am wrong.

Comment: Hi, it would help considerably if you could use Mathjax to format your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can extract a clear inductive proof from the following:

Let $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$.

You need to prove $\hat{\delta}(A, w) = C$ **iff** $w$ has the form $w=w_1 00 w_2$, where $w_1,w_2 \in \Sigma^*$.

($\Rightarrow$): Suppose $\hat{\delta}(A, w) = C$. Let $w = \alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_n$ with $\alpha_k \in \Sigma$, $\sigma_1 = A$ and $\sigma_{k+1} = \delta(\sigma_k, \alpha_k)$. Let $i$ be the first time that $\sigma_i = C$. Then we must have $\sigma_{i-1} = B$, $\alpha_{i-1} = 0$, $\sigma_{i-2} = A$ and $\alpha_{i-2} = 0$. If we let $w_1 = \alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_{i-3}$, $w_2 = \alpha_{i} \cdots \alpha_{n}$, then $w = w_1 00 w_2$.

($\Leftarrow$): Suppose $w=w_1 00 w_2$. Let $\sigma = \hat{\delta}(A, w_1)$. If $\sigma = C$ we are finished, as $\delta(C, \alpha) = C$ for all $\alpha \in \Sigma$. If $\sigma = B$, then $\hat{\delta}(A, w_1 0) = \delta(B, 0) = C$, and we are finished. Finally, If $\sigma = A$, then $\hat{\delta}(A, w_1 0) = B$ and $\delta(B, 0) = C$, hence $\hat{\delta}(A, w_1 00) = C$ which finishes the proof (since $\hat{\delta}(C, w_2) = C$).

Comment: You have shown in both the directions, and i have only in one side, is my proof incomplete?? And sorry about format, it is my first post here.

Comment: Well, since you need to describe the language exactly, you need to show equivalence. Sorry, I find your format really hard to read.